# ffmpeg: multiple video filter order issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have a problem with the ffmpeg video filters. I'm unable to get two filters to work: the scale function and the logo addition. I read about `-filter_complex` instead of `-vf`, but someone also achieved it with `-vf`. I try with commas, but for the moment it can read max one filter, otherwise it gives me an error.

```
ffmpeg -y -i $name -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $FPSC -b:v 1060k -maxrate 1060k -bufsize 530k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -vf "movie=logo480.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out], scale=-1:478" format480.mp4
```

Comment: You should always provide any errors. Better yet is to provide the complete terminal output from the ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $name -i logo480.png -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $FPSC -b:v 1060k -maxrate 1060k -bufsize 530k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=-2:478" format480.mp4
```

- `-vf` is only used for simple filters (filters with one input and one output).
- `-filter_complex` is used for complex filters (filters with one or more inputs and/or outputs). `-filter_complex` can also be used with simple filters. Basically, you can ignore `-vf`.
- Linear filter processes can be chained together with a comma.
- I changed `scale=-1:478` to `scale=-2:478` so the resulting width will be divisible by 2. This is to avoid a "not divisible by 2" error. You did not provide your error so I'm not sure if it is the error you encountered.

Comment: Thanks LordNeckbeard, I did not understand how the matrix work, your correction seems to give me a logo with the same dimension proportion for every resolution, great! (i think for the matrix, add the logo before scale options) thanks

Comment: To be fair, the OP's method is often seen and does work. The issue here is that since simple filterchains have a default output pad label of `[out]` and is assigned to the overlay result, the scale is bypassed. Removing the label altogether should make it work.

Comment: @Mulvya I don't want to encourage a legacy method that is overly complicated.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for special help, may i ask why I'm unable to force HD resolution for output as doesn't metter which was input resolution: ffmpeg -y -i $name -i logo1080.png -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $FPSC -b:v 2400k -maxrate 2400k -bufsize 1200k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=1920:1080" format-1080.mp4

I use scale=1920:1080 but i already get resolution like 1993 X 1080?